# C# Linq .Contains list of string

Tags: c#, linq, contains

How check in where line.Contains("One") more than one string? For example how select file contains line with text element of "names" List.

```cs
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  List<string> names = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };

  try
  {
    var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\Logs\", "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                where line.Contains("One")
                select new
                {
                  File = file,
                  Line = line
                };

    foreach (var f in files)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
    }
    //MessageBox.Show(files.Count().ToString() + " record found.");
    }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
  }
  catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `line.Contains("One") || line.Contains("names")`?

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify your question a little bit.  The English is a little unclear.

Comment: You need to use `any` instead of `Contains`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\Stary komp\Logi\Logs2\", "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where names.Any(name => line.Contains(name))
            select new
            {
              File = file,
              Line = line
            };
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try to use something like this:

```
line.Intersect(names).Any()
```

Although, I'm not sure whether it works inside a Linq expression?